# How to convert this Postgresql code to Snowflake? Or How is it written in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
Create function get_car_Price(Price_from int, Price_to int)  
returns int  
language plpgsql  
as  
$$  
Declare  
 Car_count integer;  
Begin  
   select count(*)   
   into Car_count  
   from Car  
   where Car_price between Price_from and Price_to;  
   return Car_count;  
End;  
$$;
```

Comment: Please don't add the `postgresql` tag. Your question is not about PostgreSQL, it's about Snowflake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation is straighforward:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_car_Price(PRICE_FROM int, PRICE_TO int)
RETURNS INT
AS 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CAR WHERE Car_price BETWEEN PRICE_FROM AND PRICE_TO';
```

Function call:

```
SELECT get_car_price(100,200);
-- 0
```

Related: [Scalar SQL UDFs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-scalar-functions.html)

Comment: Hi @Taqpatel. I am happy to hear you find this input  valuable. The way Stack Overflow works  is to provide question/answers that could be helphul for others too. Please ask new questions and I am sure the community could help.